# How to temporarily set all elements' tabindex attribute and be able to reset all elements to their original tabindex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If each element has its own `tabindex`, like below:

```
<a href="http://example.com" tabindex="3">Link</a>
<input type="text" tabindex="2">
<select tabindex="5">
    <option>Option A</option>
    <option>Option B</option>
    <option>Option C</option>
</select>
<textarea tabindex="4">Hello world</textarea>
<button tabindex="1" id="Btn">Button</button>
```

Now, I append an event to `button[id=Btn]` which sets all elements' `tabindex` into `-1`, like below:

```
document.getElementById("Btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var allElement = document.querySelectorAll("a,area,button,input,object,select,textarea");
    for(var i = 0; i < allElement.length; i++){
        allElement[i].setAttribute("tabindex",-1);
    }
});
```

After clicking the `button[id=Btn]`, how can I reset all elements to their original `tabindex`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the current `tabindex` in a `data-` attribute, and use it to restore the original tabindex value when needed:

```js
var allElement = document.querySelectorAll("a,area,button,input,object,select,textarea");

document.getElementById("Btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < allElement.length; i++) {
    allElement[i].setAttribute("data-tabindex", allElement[i].getAttribute("tabindex"));
    allElement[i].setAttribute("tabindex", -1);
  }
});

document.getElementById("BtnRes").addEventListener("click", function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < allElement.length; i++) {
    allElement[i].setAttribute("tabindex", allElement[i].getAttribute("data-tabindex"));
    allElement[i].removeAttribute("data-tabindex", -1);
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com" tabindex="3">Link</a>
<input type="text" tabindex="2">
<select tabindex="5">
    <option>Option A</option>
    <option>Option B</option>
    <option>Option C</option>
</select>
<textarea tabindex="4">Hello world</textarea>
<button tabindex="1" id="Btn">Button</button>
<button tabindex="1" id="BtnRes">restore tabindex</button>
```